# Iterate through elements and click on a button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML:

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="">program user</td>
        <td class="">program pass</td>
        <td class="">program email</td>
        <td class="">Program User</td>
        <td class="">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="">progman</td>
        <td class="">progman_name</td>
        <td class="">progman_lastname</td>
        <td class="">Program Manager</td>
        <td class="">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
```

This displays a table of users and:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
```

is the button 'x', which I am trying to locate so I can delete the user, a specific user 'Program Manager' or 'Program User'

Is this possible?

Comment: I tried this but it still finds the first 'x' button             one = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='' and text()='Program Manager']")
two = one.find_element_by_xpath('..').click()
three = two.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution:

one = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='' and text()='Program Manger']/..//span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick']")

ActionChains(driver).double_click(one).perform()

Basically the I find the class containing text "Program Manager" then I move up to its parent, then iteratively ie. with // look for the 'ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to find a specific user (for which you already know the name) and click on the associated delete button. Something like this should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your-url-here")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/td[text()='your-name-here']/../span")
elem.click()
driver.close()
```

Comment: I am trying to find a specific user as I mentioned above, but I need to specifically click on the span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span button